# How to include / exclude a struct's field in JSON dynamically?

Tags: json, go, struct

I have a ‍‍struct `Base` :

```
type Base struct {
        Name string `json:"name,omitempty"`
        // ... other fields
}
```

And two more structs that embed `Base`:

```
type First struct {
        Base
        // ... other fields
}

type Second struct {
        Base
        // ... other fields
}
```

Now I want to Marshal the structs `First` and `Second` but with a little difference. I want  to include the `Name` field in `First` but I don't want to include it in `Second`.

Or to simplify the question I want to opt in and out a struct's field in its JSON dynamically.

Note:
The `Name` value **always** has value and I don't want to change it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can implement the `Marshaler` interface for type `Second` and create a dummy type `SecondClone`.

```
type SecondClone Second

func (str Second) MarshalJSON() (byt []byte, err error) {

   var temp SecondClone
   temp = SecondClone(str)
   temp.Base.Name = ""
   return json.Marshal(temp)
}
```

This will work with no other changes to your code.

And it won't modify the value in `Name` as it works on a different type / copy.

Comment: it makes sense but I don't want to change the value! is it possible just to ignore the field in `MarshalJSON` function?

Comment: @mehdy this is the cleanest solution. Once you have set as empty the Name property the json.Marshal will not parse and you will not able to get it again using the deserializer

Comment: maybe save the value prior to Marshal()? `foo := str.Base.Name; str.Base.Name = ""; result := json.Marshal(str); str.Base.Name = foo; return result`

Comment: It's not possible! `json.Marshal(str)` leads to calling itself over and over and it'll cause stackoverflow

Comment: @mehdy Sorry about that, fixed it.

Comment: @mehdy Is there anything else to clear up in the answer ? This approach also doesn't change the value in the struct.

Comment: @JohnSPerayil the problem is it's messy and I don't like it!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
type Base struct {
    Name string `json: "name,omitempty"`
    // ... other fields
}

type First struct {
    Base
    // ... other fields
}

type Second struct {
    Base
    Name string `json: "-"`
    // ... other fields
}
```

This means you must not call Second.Base.Name anymore in the code but just Second.Name.

Comment: no it didn't work! its still there!
and even if it could work it seems a little confusing to me! it may raise some problems!